# Advanced Filter for an Entity Reference Custom Field doesn't filter by Contact Groups

Tags: custom-fields, entity-reference

I'm looking to convert a few custom fields from type "Contact Reference" to "Entity Reference".

However when I convert the fields, the autocomplete "advanced filter" stops working.

```
action=lookup&group=106
```

**BEFORE**
As a Contact Reference field, the advanced filter works fine and displays only the contacts in the specified contact group.

[image]

**AFTER**
When it becomes an Entity Reference field, the autocomplete displays ANY contact of any type, totally ignoring the filter.

[image]

I have tried playing with the advanced filter parameters but no luck. I don't see any relevant documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the old ContactReference and the new EntityReference fields is that the former uses APIv3 and the latter uses APIv4. There are subtle differences in the parameters of each. If you notice, the help text underneath "Advanced Filter" actually changes a bit when you switch to EntityRef and it gives you a working example of how to filter by contact type and group.

For a full list of available filters, use the APIv4 Explorer (Under **Support -> Developer** in the menubar). Any fields available in the "Where" clause for Contact.get can be used as filters.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for pointing out the change in the fine print. This works now:
`action=get&groups=106`